# select nested element with :has

Tags: html, css

I have a html structure like this:

```
<kendo-label>
 <label class="k-label"></label>
</kendo-label>
<kendo-textbox class="k-input-solid"></kendo-textbox>
```

If I click in the textbox (focus), the label should have a different color. For this I have this selector, which works well:

```
kendo-label:has(+ .k-input-solid:focus-within) .k-label {
  color: var(--blue-05);
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

Now, I have a new structure with a `div` like this:

```
<kendo-label>
  <label class="k-label"></label>
</kendo-label>
<div>
  <kendo-textbox class="k-input-solid"></kendo-textbox>
</div>
```

This `div` is inserted by the component provider, so I have to accept it as it is.

The question is, how can I now achieve the same result?

I tried this:

```
kendo-label:has(+ div):has(+ .k-input-solid:focus-within) .k-label {
  color: var(--blue-05);
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

But the label isn't selected.

With this I get selected the label:

```
kendo-label:has(+ div) .k-label {
  color: var(--blue-05);
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

But I need this rule only, if the textbox has focus. How should I attach this rule too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the requirements into the same `has` function:

```
kendo-label:has(+ div .k-input-solid:focus-within) .k-label {
  color: var(--blue-05);
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```css
.test:has(+ div .k-input-solid:focus) .k-label {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <label class="k-label">test</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input class="k-input-solid"/>
</div>
```